# How to get the systems Battery Percentage in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, xcode, widgetkit

I'm trying to include a battery feature to my widget, but I can't seem to get the mobile's battery percentage...

I tried:

```
import UIKit

struct BatteryControl {
    static func getBatteryPercent() -> Int {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        print("BATTERY : \(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel)")
        return Int(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100)
    }
}
```

It just keeps showing that the battery is -1.0

**EDIT**
SOLUTION: Simulator always showing the batter as -1.0, but whem testing it on a real deivce, it showed the correct value.

Comment: Are you testing on real device? I guess on simulator it will always return this number.

Answer (score 1):

The battery monitoring must be enabled in the method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of the `AppDelegate`

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
        return true
    }
```

Comment: No, testing it on a real device worked. The simulator is always returning -1.0